# Google map resize android

Tags: android

I have a map occupying my entire screen. On marker click, I add button below map view and shrink the map size. Doing this makes the full screen map blink and change its dimensions. What can I do about it?

Then following java code adds button on marker click:

```
public void createMarkerMenu(MyLocation myLocation) {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.markerMenu);
    Button route = new Button(this);
    route.setText(myLocation.getEmail());
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
    layout.addView(route);
}
```

The xml structure is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
    //map view
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
    //empty. Adding button here from java file
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I would add some code maybe, then will talk.

Comment: @Tarson Added the code.

Comment: when clicking the button to resize map what does the android monitor/logcat say any issues/errors upon clicking the button?

Comment: No I don't get any errors. The re-sizing of map is pretty distinct that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try going through your code and using the tips below that can help avoid the Google maps flickering. After research I have found that it is a common issue.

To avoid Google maps flickering bug:

Don't do "add" or "replace" operations with the fragment which contains Google map fragment inside. 
Instead, use show/hide operations with the fragment view. This will not recreate already created fragment when you use these operations. For example:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();  
FragmentTransaction fT1 = manager.beginTransaction();
fT1.show (someFragments);
fT1.hide (someFragments2);
fT1.commit();
```

During app execution, don't try to change google map fragment dimension parameters `width, height, margin, etc...` at all. Search workarounds by using another (additional) views if you need some google map animations, width changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a xml structure like this:

```
<RelativeLayout>
    //map view

    <LinearLayout>
        //empty. Adding button here from java file
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/markerMenu"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Since I've set the width and height on the `markerMenu` layout in the xml, you can remove it from your `createMarkerMenu()` method:

```
public void createMarkerMenu(MyLocation myLocation) {
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.markerMenu);
    Button route = new Button(this);
    route.setText(myLocation.getEmail());
    layout.addView(route);
}
```